# Sending Augur through Geth

Tags: transactions

I'm currently trying to work on sending Augur (REP) through geth. I've got the abi in, I can check my balance, I receive a `txid` after executing the transfer, but the tx never shows up on etherscan.

```
augur_abi = [{augur_abi is here}]

contract = web3.eth.contract(augur_abi).at('0x48c80F1f4D53D5951e5D5438B54Cba84f29F32a5');

contract.transfer("addressgoeshere",500000000000000000);
```

This is what I have so far. I should note that I'm running Parity 1.3.3 in Geth mode. The amount attempting to send with this particular test being .5

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [EtherScan.io - REP](https://etherscan.io/token/REP):

```
var repAddress = "0xe94327d07fc17907b4db788e5adf2ed424addff6";
```

From [augur-core/src/repContractAbi](https://github.com/AugurProject/augur-core/blob/develop/src/repContractAbi):

```
var repABIFragment = [{"name": "transfer", "type": "function", "constant": false, "inputs": [{ "name": "receiver", "type": "address" }, { "name": "fxpValue", "type": "uint256" }], "outputs": [{ "name": "out", "type": "uint256" }]}];
```

Define the contract variable:

```
var repContract = web3.eth.contract(repABIFragment).at(repAddress);
```

Unlock your account:

```
var fromAccount = eth.accounts[0];
var toAccount = “{Destination account}”;
personal.unlockAccount(fromAccount, "<Your Password>");
```

Transfer the tokens:

```
var txId = repContract.transfer(toAccount, 500000000000000000, {from:fromAccount});
```

From a [sample REP `transfer(...)` transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x39d56157571b27b2c893cca795fda29552d61fbd04bfac56fb4b890b5c21cf70), the default 90000 gas will suffice. Otherwise you can bump up the gas amount in the statement above by changing `{from:fromAccount}` to `{from:fromAccount, gas: 150000}` for example.

Comment: Thanks! Excellent answer, couldn't ask for a better response.

Answer (score 2):

An even bigger noob here: where do I get the augur_abi from? Did you manage to get it to work?

- Any op can please add this as a comment to his post? (I don't have the reputation - 50 - to comment).

Comment: Just responding to the first part of your comment. The Augur ABI can be found at https://github.com/AugurProject/augur-core/blob/develop/src/repContractAbi .